# Pandas split columns on first % sign, on 2nd letter

Tags: python, pandas

We have the following dataframe

```
# raw_df
print(raw_df.to_dict())

{'Edge': {1: '-1.9%-2.2%', 2: '+5.8%-9.4%', 3: '+3.5%-7.2%'}, 'Grade': {1: 'D+D', 2: 'BF', 3: 'B-F'}}
```

[image]

We are trying to split these 2 columns into 4 columns. The **Edge** column should split after the first `%`, and the **Grade** column should split before the 2nd capital letter appears. The output should look like:

```
output_df

edge_1 edge_2 grade_1 grade_2
 -1.9%  -2.2%      D+       D
 +5.8%  -9.4%       B       F
 +3.5%  -7.2%      B-       F
```

We have `raw_df[['t1_grade', 't2_grade']] = raw_df['Grade'].str.extractall(r'([A-Z])').unstack()` to split the **Grade** column, however the + and - are dropped here, which is a problem. And we are not sure how to split the **Edge** column after the first % appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str.extract` as follows:

```py
df["edge_1"] = df["Edge"].str.extract(r'^([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)')
df["edge_2"] = df["Edge"].str.extract(r'([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)$')
df["grade_1"] = df["Grade"].str.extract(r'^([A-Z][+-]?)')
df["grade_2"] = df["Grade"].str.extract(r'([A-Z][+-]?)$')
```

The strategy here is to extract the first/last percentage/grade from the two current columns using regex.

Comment: this is great, although we get an `NaN` in the `edge_1` column with this

Comment: Try the updated answer.  The previous version was making each decimal value a mandatory float, when your actual data might have some whole numbers in there.

Comment: hmm, so my fuller data has some examples where edge 1 is `1%`, rather than `1.3%` or some decimal - amazing, new solution works!

Comment: nice +10, can also combine the `Grade` extractions into one call: `df[['grade_1', 'grade_2']] = df['Grade'].str.extract(r'([A-Z][-+]?)([A-Z][-+]?)')`

Comment: @tdy I have never seen an example of using `str.extract` with more than one capture group.  Learned something new today (+1 to your answer as well).